# 302 found and the data is not returned using ajax in the MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using AJAX call in JS and calling a controller and action method with the url

I ran the code in my local it is working fine but when it was deployed in production the AJAX call didn't get the data and it is throwing a message in console

Could not load content for https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/JavaScript/JavaScriptSDK/ajax/ajax.ts (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)

The data on local is limited but it has more data on production

I tried it by calling through AJAX and from the action method I am returning the data in the JSON format and the data i recieved is parsed and then it is sent to a hidden field it was running fine on my local all the data is there but when it was deployed on production after the page load the ajax will be called but I can't able to see the data and it shows the error which I mentioned above.

[image: the pic attached is the network here when I checked the action method it is showing the status code as 302 found]

[image: This is the data in the hidden field it is loading script instead of the data]

[image: This is my AJAX code and in the URL I called the controller/actionmethod]

[image: Thi the is action method in the controller and it returns the data in json form "sorry for the clarity"]

Comment: 404 is not found.  Are you sure that path is correct?  Is it suppose to be `ajax.js` perhaps?

Comment: @hijinxbassist could you please let me know where should I check it. this error was on browser. so should I check the file location of ajax.js file??

Comment: You can use the browser's developer tools to check if the code is being included in the site correctly, on Chrome you can use the network section in production to see if the files are being loaded.

Comment: @ShiinZu I have attached the pictures of the network section and it is showing 302 found on the action method which I called using AJAX

Comment: @sadiqshaik your second image shows your result is a complete HTML page not a json object. Your call is returning an error. Maybe check if you web.config has the correct path to the database?

Comment: @ShiinZu the web.config has correct path and the connection string is given through the azure all the other data is coming from db and it is displayed on page but only for the ajax call i gave controller/action method showing the 302 found status code

Comment: @ShiinZu I also attached the images of the controller, action method and the ajax call in the js

Answer (score 0):

I will give you two recommendations that work better for me when dealing with passing JSON data from a controller.

First try this on your get data method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult Getsubscriptiondata()
{
    var subdata = db.ExistingSubscriptionList.Where(substatus => substatus.OSCP_SubStatusId == "1").ToList();

    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subdata));
}
```

Second in your javascript change the line

```
document.getElementById('hdnExistingSubs').value = JSON.stringify(data)
```

to

```
document.getElementById('hdnExistingSubs').value = JSON.parse(data)
```

This gives me more consistent results when receiving data from the controller, hope this helps.

Clarification: I prefer this methods because passing a Json result sometimes haves quirks in the way the data is rendered on the javascript in the browser.

Comment: Thanks this one worked a small edit i would suggest is instead of [httpGet] I used [httpPost] and it is working fine. Thanks again